# upgrade Active directory 2003 to 2012R2 profile user

Tags: active-directory, user-profile

I have problem about profile user

I have a Domain with 2 domain controller (both of them is 2003) and install new domain controller (windows 2012R2)

some user in domain  when login to domain all of data move to  temporary folder then create new profile directory

any body here which have similar problem and how can I solve it ?

Comment: You didn't mention which version of Windows you're having the problem on, you didn't say you checked the event viewer for error logs, you didn't try to login with the same user on a different machine. do all of that and I think you'll have a good chance to fix the mess.

Comment: I have two windows 2003 SP2 which has DC role and one windows 2012R2 and client is windows 7 - user login same machine and nothing special event in event viewer

Answer (score 0):

You either have a corrupted profile, or the security settings on your profile are wrong.

Before using any of the below fixes, I'd highly recommend you to take a backup of the machine in question to avoid losing data in case something went wrong.

There is a lot of talk on the steps that you need to follow, to save time and formating, I'll just post you a link to the [Microsoft Knowledge Base Article 947215](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947215) which should address the problem you're having.